# Python inspect ismethod

Tags: python

I am trying to use inspect to find out if foo is a method of object test_me. I want it to return True or False. This is what I have tried.

```
import inspect

class Object:
    pass

test_me = Object()

inspect.ismethod(test.foo())
```

This gives me the Error. I am looking to return false.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    inspect.ismethod(o.foo())
AttributeError: Object instance has no attribute 'foo'
```

Then if I try this:

```
class Object:
    def foo(self,x):
        return x
test_me = Object()

inspect.ismethod(test_me.foo(5)) # return false.
```

How can I:

1.) check inspect.ismethod of object in the first example where I can get True or False.

2.) Then in the second example how can I make foo a method of object and  inspect.ismethod return   True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code raises the exception because the code is trying to access non-existing attribute (method). You can work-around this by using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) with fallback default value. (`None` will be okay because `None` is not a method)

```
getattr(test_me, 'foo', None)
```

The second code returns `False` because the code passes the return value of the method call (`x` or 5), not the method itself.

```
inspect.ismethod(test_me.foo)
```

So, the final code should looks like following line:

```
inspect.ismethod(getattr(test_me, 'foo', None))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, check that `foo` exists before checking if it's a method:

```
>>> hasattr(test, 'foo')
False
```

In the second case, don't call the method, just pass it:

```
>>> inspect.ismethod(test.foo)
False
```

So together,

```
hasattr(test, 'foo') and inspect.ismethod(test.foo)
```

is `False` unless `foo` both exists and is a method.

Comment: I've fixed that now. Your answer is probably better anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
inspect.ismethod(test_me.foo())
```

You appear to have misspelled the variable name you wanted to examine.